# How to change the badge background color in UIBarbutton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uibarbuttonitemstyle, uibaritem

I am using uibarbutton in my view to show the notification badge number. I have used following code to display.

```
barButtonBadge.badgeValue = @"5";
```

How can I change the background color of this badge number?
Right now it is taking default color.

Comment: A badge is a small red oval that displays the number of pending notification items (a badge appears over the upper-right corner of an app’s icon). You have no control over the size or color of the badge.

Comment: https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge

Answer (score 0):

Through your good question i got the solution from above Lalit Kumar link.

```
Add following two libraries in your project

     1. UIButton+Badge.h and UIButton+Badge.m
     2. UIBarButtonItem+Badge.h and  UIBarButtonItem+Badge.m


Also import 

      #import "UIButton+Badge.h"
      #import "UIBarButtonItem+Badge.h"  in required view controller.


 in your required ViewController.m

      UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage"];
      UIBarButtonItem *navRightButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image2
                                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                                 target:self
                                                                 action:@selector(buttonPress:)];
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = navRightButton;
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.badgeValue = @"2";
     self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.badgeBGColor = [UIColor orangeColor]; //Whatever you want just change the color
```